# Rendering differently in different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is one html file which is rendering differently in edge browser and chrome. While correcting UserInterface for one browser by making changes in height and width of different labels in html file, it is breaking UI in chrome. I am not able to align the UI properly in both browsers. How do I resolve it? Please help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
<title>ZZZZ Tab</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="/code/ski/current_1/UI/web/css/aa.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="/code/ski/current_1/stylesheets/bb.css" />

<script src="/UI/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/UI/js/cash/ZZZZ.js"></script>
<script src="/sha/js/ui/get.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.Total_Label {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #003366;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="Center" onload="page_Load();">

    <div style="position: absolute; top: 8; left: 550;">
        <input type="button" id="DD" class="si_Button" style="width: 60px;"
            tabIndex="1" onClick="onClickDDDD()" value="D" />
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 38; left: 445;">
        <input type="button" id="BalButton" class="si_Button"
            style="width: 60px;" tabIndex="3" onClick="VltBalance()"
            value="Get Bal" />
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 38; left: 550;">
        <input type="button" id="DDDD" class="si_Button" style="width: 60px;"
            tabIndex="4" onClick="ClickVlt()" value="DD" />
    </div>

    <div id="zzzz" align="left" style="z-index: 1">
        <table border="0" cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5'
            style="height: 350px; width: 90%">
            <tr>
                <td width="15%" class="General" nowrap="nowrap"><span
                    id="tell_ddraw"></span></td>
                <td width="20%" align="right"><span id="tel_Bal"></span></td>
                <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="30%"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="15%"><select id="vD" name="val" tabindex="2"
                    onchange="getvB(this);">
                </select></td>
                <td width="20%" align="right"><span id="vB"></span></td>
                <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="30%"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" valign="top">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="Label"><input type="radio" name="BuyOrSell"
                                id="BuyVal" checked="checked" tabindex="5" /> <label
                                for="BuyVal">Buy from Val</label></td>
                            <td class="Label"><input type="radio" name="BuyOrSell"
                                id="sellToVal" tabindex="6" /> <label for="sellToVal">Sell
                                    to Val</label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <table width="45%" cellspacing="3">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="headerTitle" align="center">Bill
                                Count</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="Label">&nbsp;Count</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="Label">Value</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="bill_100" type="text" tabindex="7" size="4"
                                maxlength="7" value="0" class="format" format="+ve_number"
                                onblur="Bill(this)" style="text-align: right;" /></td>
                            <td class="Label">x 100</td>
                            <td><input id="bill_100_amt" type="text" tabindex="8"
                                size="9" maxlength="12" value="$0.00" class="format"
                                format="+ve_currency" disabled="true" style="text-align: right;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="bill_50" type="text" tabindex="9" size="4"
                                maxlength="7" value="0" class="format" format="+ve_number"
                                onblur="Bill(this)" style="text-align: right;" /></td>
                            <td class="Label">x 50</td>
                            <td><input id="bill_50_amt" type="text" tabindex="10"
                                size="9" maxlength="12" value="$0.00" class="format"
                                format="+ve_currency" disabled="true" style="text-align: right;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="bill_20" type="text" tabindex="11" size="4"
                                maxlength="7" value="0" class="format" format="+ve_number"
                                onblur="Bill(this)" style="text-align: right;" /></td>
                            <td class="Label">x 20</td>
                            <td><input id="bill_amt" type="text" tabindex="12" size="9"
                                maxlength="12" value="$0.00" class="format"
                                format="+ve_currency" disabled="true" style="text-align: right;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="bill_10" type="text" tabindex="13" size="4"
                                maxlength="7" value="0" class="format" format="+ve_number"
                                onblur="Bill(this)" style="text-align: right;" /></td>
                            <td class="Label">x 10</td>
                            <td><input id="bill_10_amt" type="text" tabindex="14"
                                size="9" maxlength="12" value="$0.00" class="format"
                                format="+ve_currency" disabled="true" style="text-align: right;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="bill_5" type="text" tabindex="15" size="4"
                                maxlength="7" value="0" class="format" format="+ve_number"
                                onblur="Bill(this)" style="text-align: right;" /></td>
                            <td class="Label">x 5</td>
                            <td><input id="bill_5_amt" type="text" tabindex="16"
                                size="9" maxlength="12" value="$0.00" class="format"
                                format="+ve_currency" disabled="true" style="text-align: right;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="bill_1" type="text" tabindex="17" size="4"
                                maxlength="7" value="0" class="format" format="+ve_number"
                                onblur="Bill(this)" style="text-align: right;" /></td>
                            <td class="Label">x 1</td>
                            <td><input id="bill_1_amt" type="text" tabindex="18"
                                size="9" maxlength="12" value="$0.00" class="format"
                                format="+ve_currency" disabled="true" style="text-align: right;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="height: 6px"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="Total" style="position: absolute; top: 280px; left: 570px;">
        Total</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 280px; left: 620px;">
        <input id="total_bills" type="text" tabindex="19" size="12"
            maxlength="12" value="" onchange="onChange(this);"
            onblur="TotalAmount(this);" style="text-align: right;" />
    </div>
    <div
        style="position: absolute; top: 310px; left: 602px; height: 30px; width: 80px">
        <input type="button" id="cancelButton" class="si_Button"
            style="width: 60px;" tabIndex="20" onClick="Cancel()" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
    <div
        style="position: absolute; top: 310px; left: 670px; height: 30px; width: 80px">
        <input type="button" id="submitButton" class="si_Button"
            style="width: 60px;" tabIndex="21" onClick="Submit()" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a *"normalize css"* file  (easily found on web) to make sure each browser is using same defaults. User can personalize some of the defaults  in browser preferences settings and that can throw layouts off unless you reset with your own style rules

Comment: Only show the affected parts. You should have 4-10 lines and optimally a screenshot of the variance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *"normalize css"* file  (easily found on web) to make sure each browser is using same defaults.

A user can personalize some of the defaults  in their browser preferences settings and that can throw layouts off unless you reset with your own style rules